# Any good example for ros_control of diff drive robot

Tags: ros, differential-drive, ros-control, ros-kinetic, gazebo-ros-control

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm looking for examples related to ros_control of differential drive robot.
Please list any real or simulated diff-drive robots (with source code references) that use ros_control.
Such references will tremendously help newbie's like me to get a grasp of ros_control.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/305022/any-good-example-for-ros_control-of-diff-drive-robot/) by [kiranpalla](https://answers.ros.org/users/35388/kiranpalla/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-10-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here is a link to ros_control Git: https://github.com/ros-controls/ros_control/wiki . There are some code samples where you can learn about the basics of ros_control in there and you can take it from there. I think Universal Robots also use ros_control, double check about it though. Here youtube tutorial programming their UR5 robot, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J6Mu1P6FlxY

---

Originally posted by [srikanth262](https://answers.ros.org/users/37946/srikanth262/) with karma: 16 on 2018-10-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0